# OpenXML, объединенные ячейки в WORD

Tags: openxml

Немного не понял из документации, что означает значение Restart и Continue в свойстве `VerticalMerge`.

Я правильно понимаю, что этим атрибутом отмечается начало последовательности?

В чем разница между Restart и Continue?

Comment: Скорее всего restart - означает что именно с этой ячейки началось обьединение (вниз), а Continue - означает, что эта ячейка обьеденена с ячейкой, которая выше.

Comment: @nick_n_a, хм... не самые лучшие названия они выбрали=(